# Fetching Outlook Contacts with Python

Tags: python, outlook

I am given a task to fetch all the contacts from (Microsoft)Outlook using Python. I tried this :

```
import win32com.client
object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = object.GetNamespace("MAPI")
print ns
```

It gave me the output :

```
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library._NameSpace instance at 0x12528376>
```

I understand that `ns` is now an Object but does it give me access to `Outlook` contacts ?
If yes then how should I fetch the contacts ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import win32com.client
import pywintypes

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
profile = ns.Folders.Item("Profile Name")
contacts = profile.Folders.Item("Contacts")
```