# Read contacts detail from outlook by Python win32com

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I did some research on this topic. I saw this cookbook [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/173216-import-outlook-contacts-using-win32com/) and tried. It worked fine, but after some udpate/repair of my Outlook, it does not work anymore. The error message is `AttributeError: olFolderContacts`.

I also tried this suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537808/fetching-outlook-contacts-with-python), but doesn't worked.

The error message is `com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)`.

Could anyone help to identify the problem?

the code is here:

```
import win32com.client
import sys
DEBUG = 0

class MSOutlook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outlookFound = 0
        try:
            self.oOutlookApp = \
                win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
            self.outlookFound = 1
        except:
            print ("MSOutlook: unable to load Outlook")

        self.records = []


    def loadContacts(self, keys=None):
        if not self.outlookFound:
            return

        # this should use more try/except blocks or nested blocks
        onMAPI = self.oOutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        ofContacts = \
            onMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olContact)

        if DEBUG:
            print ("number of contacts:", len(ofContacts.Items))

        for oc in range(len(ofContacts.Items)):
            contact = ofContacts.Items.Item(oc + 1)
            if contact.Class == win32com.client.constants.olContact:
                if keys is None:
                    # if we were't give a set of keys to use
                    # then build up a list of keys that we will be
                    # able to process
                    # I didn't include fields of type time, though
                    # those could probably be interpreted
                    keys = []
                    for key in contact._prop_map_get_:
                        if isinstance(getattr(contact, key), (int, str, 'unicode')):
                            keys.append(key)
                    if DEBUG:
                        keys.sort()
                        print ("Fields\n======================================")
                        for key in keys:
                            print (key)
                record = {}
                for key in keys:
                    record[key] = getattr(contact, key)
                if DEBUG:
                    print (oc, record['FullName'])
                self.records.append(record)


    def output(self):
        dic={}
        for i in self.records:
            dic[i['FullName']] = [i['Email1Address']]

        return dic



if __name__ == '__main__':
    if DEBUG:
        print ("attempting to load Outlook")
    oOutlook = MSOutlook()
    # delayed check for Outlook on win32 box
    if not oOutlook.outlookFound:
        print( "Outlook not found")
        sys.exit(1)

    fields = ['FullName',
                'Email1Address',
                ]

    if DEBUG:
        import time
        print ("loading records...")
        startTime = time.time()
    # you can either get all of the data fields
    # or just a specific set of fields which is much faster
    #oOutlook.loadContacts()
    oOutlook.loadContacts(fields)
    if DEBUG:
        print ("loading took %f seconds" % (time.time() - startTime))

    for i in oOutlook.records:

        print ("Contact: %s" % i['FullName'])
        print ("Contact: %s" % i['Email1Address'])
```

Comment: Please post the relevant snippet  of your code that causes the exception.